# PHP: After setting the constructor, why I can´t use the property´s own name?

Tags: php, oop, constructor

I´m learning about PHP objects, and constructors.

I have this simple example:

```
class ShopProduct {
private $title;

public function __construct($title) {
$this->title = $title;
}

public function getTitle() {
return $this->title;
}
}
```

What I don´t understand is why would I do this assign inside the constructor, only to keep using `$this->title` in next functions?

I mean, after creating the constructor, why do I do this:

```
public function getTitle() {
return $this->title;
}
```

instead of this?

```
public function getTitle() {
return $title;
}
```

Thanks for your clarification. Sorry about my lousy and maybe unaccurate english :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a problem with code.

Comment: The language is designed that way. There is no going around it. As for why, perhaps it makes easier on both PHP developers and PHP users to distinguish between class properties and local-scope variables?

Comment: Because of the setting veriables, before on load of class.

Comment: I thought people could ask doubts of any kind about code, not just specific problems. (There are plenty of other "in theory" questions here) without any close votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class property can either have a different value for each class instance (object) or it can have the same value, such that each instance can keep track of it. In your example, $title is going to be different for each class, so when you say

```
$this->title
```

You are effectively saying 'get me the title of *this* particular instance that the method is being called upon'.

Answer (score 1):

Because that is how the language works.

How would you refer to a variable called `$title` in the parent scope, if member functions always had an implicit `$this->` on all of their variable accesses?

How would you have a local variable named `$title` *and* a member variable called `$this->title` in the same function?

Suddenly this wouldn't work...

```
function setTitle($title) {
   $this->title = $title;
}
```